# Select sets from a list which are in ascending order

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of sets I want to choose the sets whose elements are in ascending order. I think I need to use: `Select[list, crit]` for this problem, but I could not set the criteria.

For instance,

I have a list:

```
list = {{1,4,2,3}, {4,2,3,1}, {1,4,8,9}, {1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, {2,1,3,5}, {4,8,9,10}, {2,7,9,11,13}, {4,1,7,9}};
```

From this list,  I would like to obtain the list

```
{{1,4,8,9}, {1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}, {4,8,9,10}, {2,7,9,11,13}}
```

Comment: As an alternative `Pick[list, LessEqual[##] & @@@ list]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`OrderedQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderedQ):

```
Select[OrderedQ] @ list
```

> {{1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 11, 13}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{1, 4, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7},
   {2, 4, 6, 8}, {2, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 11, 13}, {4, 1, 7, 9}};
```

Using `LongestOrderedSequence` (new in 10.2)

```
Intersection[list, LongestOrderedSequence /@ list]
```

{{1, 3, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9,
11, 13}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 4, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, 
        {2, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 11, 13}, {4, 1, 7, 9}};
```

Using `Pick` and `Differences`:

```
Pick[#, AllTrue[Differences@#, # > 0 &] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 11, 13}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some variants (I have voted for @CarlWoll):

```
Pick[list, # == Sort@# & /@ list]
Cases[list, x_?(Sort[#] == # &)]
Select[# == Sort[#] &][list]
Reap[Sow[#, #==Sort[#] ]&/@ list, True][[2,1]]
```

All yield: {{1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9,
11, 13}}

Answer (score 1):

Point-free variations:

```
list = {{1, 4, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4,
     6, 8}, {2, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 11, 13}, {4, 1, 7, 
    9}};

Select[Apply[And]@*Positive@*Differences][list]

Pick[list, Apply[And]@*Positive@*Differences /@ list]

Pick[list, Map[Apply[And]@*Positive@*Differences][list]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {4, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9,
> 11, 13}}